# failed to load video stream in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

hey guys i am developing a tv station live streaming android application now i have the url of streaming engine which look 
http://197.243.19.131:1935/rtv/rtv/playlist.m3u8

anyone can help me find out how to play video from that url in android please help i have tried to write some codes Here:

```
String stream_url="http://197.243.19.131:1935/rtv/rtv/playlist.m3u8";
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
videoView=(VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoStream);
Uri uri= Uri.parse(stream_url);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: Does this stream work for you on an outside app? Browser ? VLC Player? Also, which device are you testing it? HLS is not fully supported on all Android OS and devices.

Comment: yes this stream work on vlc network stream

Answer (score 1):

You Need to dive little more into media and streaming, though you have declared view to render video you haven't handled media Yet.
You need to use Media Player Api Provided by Android to Stream this m3u8.it is pretty Simple to play Live content follow this code.

```
  public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
      SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {


   private String Downloadurl;
   private int playminute;
   private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
   private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
   private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
   ProgressBar p_bar;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
   // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
  // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
  // hide the navigation bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

  //        thumburl = getIntent().getStringExtra("thumburl");
  //        p_bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.p_bar);
    // entryid =  getIntent().getStringExtra("entryid");
    // playminute =  getIntent().getIntExtra("playminute",0);
    //fragmenttype =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fragmenttype");
   //   Downloadurl = getIntent().getStringExtra("Downloadurl");
    Downloadurl = "http://197.243.19.131:1935/rtv/rtv/playlist.m3u8";
    // Description =  getIntent().getStringExtra("Description");
       Log.e("kanish","Download Url inside player:"+Downloadurl);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(PlayerActivity.this);
    }

     @Override
     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    p_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Downloadurl);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(PlayerActivity.this);
        //mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    }

   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    p_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
       releaseMediaPlayer();
      }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
     }

   private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
      if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
  }

}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Tested on tv emulator,streams Well:
[image: Streaming on emulator]

Comment: You can select answer as correct if it helped. It will help other folks landing on this question to find working solution

Comment: it has failed to play say in log that ava.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64
09-15 05:03:06.397 22633-22633/com.dukire.dukireapp W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `OnPreparedListener`.

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        videoview.start();
    }
});
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/).